# What is "style-warning: implicitly creating new generic function" in lisp?

Tags: warnings, common-lisp, sbcl

What does this warning mean? I have an example I used below, with this warning. Am I doing it wrong somewhere?

```
(defvar B_00 0)
(defvar B_000 0)
(defvar w_000 0)
(defvar w_00 0)
(defconstant white 0)

(defclass board ()
 ((blocker    :accessor blocker    :initarg :blocker    :initform  0)
  (friends    :accessor friends    :initarg :friends    :initform (make-array '(2)))
  (kings      :accessor kings      :initarg :kings      :initform (make-array '(2)))
  (boards     :accessor boards     :initarg :boards     :initform (make-array '(2 7) :initial-element 0))
  (enpassant  :accessor enpassant  :initarg :enpassant  :initform -1)
  (color      :accessor color      :initarg :color      :initform  WHITE)
  (castling   :accessor castling   :initarg :castling   :initform  (logior B_000 B_00 W_000 W_00))
  (hasCastled :accessor hasCastled :initarg :hasCastled :initform  (make-array '(2) :initial-element nil))
  (fifty      :accessor fifty      :initarg :fifty      :initform 0)
  (checked    :accessor checked    :initarg :checked    :initform nil)
  (opchecked  :accessor opchecked  :initarg :opchecked  :initform nil)
  (arBoard    :accessor arBoard    :initarg :arBoard    :initform (make-array '(64))) 
  (hash       :accessor hash       :initarg :hash       :initform 0)
  (pawnhash   :accessor pawnhash   :initarg :pawnhash   :initform 0)
  (history    :accessor history    :initarg :history    :initform '())))

(defmethod ischecked ((b board)) b)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define a generic function using [DEFGENERIC](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defgen.htm) before defining any methods implementing it. A method definition with no matching generic function definition will create a generic function automatically (that is, implicitly). But, if you define a generic function yourself, even if you do not need any features specific to `defgeneric` (although the interface documentation is a good idea), you will be warned if you misspell the name in any of the method definitions. It also makes it clear what the arguments should be if they are ever changed and become mismatched between methods.